# panStop method of GestureListener interface never called

Tags: libgdx

I'm implementing GestureListener interface for detecting touch events and everything works well except that panStop method is never called. It looks like:

```
public boolean panStop(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    initialZoom = pg.zoom;
    hud.released();
    return false;
}
```

But, as I said it's never called. Pan is working well, just, when I stop panning and lift my finger nothing happens. What I did wrong here? Do I have to call super methods in my implemented methods maybe?

Basically I have to detect when user lifts it's finger from the screen. There is touchDown method but not touchUp ?!?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use touchup you have to call :

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputProcessor() {

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        return true;
    }
}
```

for the panStop() i think you need to put the return to **True** instead of 
**return false**

Hope this was helpful

good luck !

Edit : try this

```
public boolean panStop(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    initialZoom = pg.zoom;
    hud.released();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: To put return to True where? What method has to return true?

Comment: the panStop method must retrun "true"

Comment: Didn't help. Method is just never called. :(

Comment: Tried to set that all the methods to return true, but that also didn't help.